# Finding and retrieving rows for which values of two columns are different

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe (~36K rows, 3 columns) part of which is shown below.

|  | hgnc_symbol | ensembl_gene_id | external_synonym |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1CF | ENSG00000148584 | ACF |
| 2 | A1CF | ENSG00000148584 | ACF64 |
| 3 | A1CF | ENSG00000148584 | ACF65 |
| 4 | A1CF | ENSG00000148584 | APOBEC1CF |
| 5 | A1CF | ENSG00000148584 | ASP |
| 6 | A2M | ENSG00000175899 | CPAMD5 |
| 7 | A2M | ENSG00000175899 | FWP007 |
| 8 | A2M | ENSG00000175899 | S863-7 |
| 9 | A2ML1 | ENSG00000166535 | CPAMD9 |
| 10 | A2ML1 | ENSG00000166535 | FLJ25179 |
| 11 | A2ML1 | ENSG00000166535 | p170 |
| 12 | AADAC | ENSG00000114771 | CES5A1 |
| 13 | AADAC | ENSG00000114771 | DAC |
| 14 | AADACL2 | ENSG00000261846 | MGC72001 |
| 15 | AADACL2 | ENSG00000197953 | MGC72001 |

I would like to find rows for which the **hgnc_symbol** column values are the same *but* the **ensembl_gene_id** column value is different. I would like to retrieve such entries. The result in this case should look something like this:

|  | hgnc_symbol | ensembl_gene_id | external_synonym |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | AADACL2 | ENSG00000261846 | MGC72001 |
| 15 | AADACL2 | ENSG00000197953 | MGC72001 |

I would really appreciate any solutions to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can `group_by` your relevant columns, then `filter` for number of observations `n()` that equals 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(hgnc_symbol, ensembl_gene_id) %>% filter(n() == 1)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   hgnc_symbol, ensembl_gene_id [2]
  hgnc_symbol ensembl_gene_id external_synonym
  <chr>       <chr>           <chr>           
1 AADACL2     ENSG00000261846 MGC72001        
2 AADACL2     ENSG00000197953 MGC72001
```